# Git rebase hangs out and creates many sh.exe processes

Tags: git, phpstorm

I am using latest PhpStorm and latest git 64 bit on Windows 10 x64. When I'm trying to do rebase option from PhpStorm then it pretty much hangs out and creates a lot of `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe` which are doing nothing, not using CPU etc. It's like 500 processes total and still counting.

What's going on? Does someone know a fix? I tried already to cloning repository again too and still the same issue.

Comment: Can you rebase successfully via command line? Are there any errors or clues in Help > Show Log in Explorer > idea.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it, when installing i disabled some cache thing, and in phpstorm settings i chose ssh executable native from built-in. Not sure which one fixed it.